# How can I set a background pattern to begin repeating from the center of my page?

Tags: html, css

I want a background to repeat-x at the top of my page, but I want it to begin repeating from the center, not across the whole page. For example something like this:

[image]

Comment: CSS can't do this: there is no way to partition the background area into quadrants.

Comment: afEkenholm was able to do it with CSS :)

Comment: I stand corrected! I was thinking of an extra div to hold the background, but a pseudo element is just as good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the `::after` pseudo selector like this:

```css
body::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/2xPV3gf.png') repeat-x left top;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vf4Rm/

Comment: You will need to add `z-index: -1;` to make sure that the rest of the content is painted over (in front of) the pseudo element.  See my answer below for similar approach without pseudo element.

Comment: Thanks @MarcAudet, I'll put it in there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple background CSS declaration

`background-position: center;`

`background-repeat: repeat-x;`

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/Mt2JS/ I want it to begin from the center and then start repeating.

Comment: But that's not what I'm asking. I want it to begin from the center. Like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yIXFZ.jpg

Comment: The only way i can think of is by using one background-image an `center` `right` it. Here is an example. I used background size to stretch it because i dont have an image the correct size http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/Mt2JS/4/

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
background-position:center;
```

but you also need:

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

along with it.

[see this page from w3schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mt2JS/2/)

Comment: I don't want the background to be centered. I want it to repeat horizontally beginning from the center. background-position center would just center it on the screen. I believe this is what you're suggesting does: http://jsfiddle.net/Mt2JS/

Comment: sorry, it doesn't seem to do what I want. This is what i want it to do: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yIXFZ.jpg which definitely is not what your suggestion does as you can see in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, but that's absolutely not what I want it to do. I really appreciate you trying to help. Can you see my image in my original post? I want it to begin from the middle, not repeat-y on the left.

Comment: @talena6 i dont think you can repeat with a starting position but you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/Mt2JS/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<div class="bg-skew"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
```

Use a separate element to hold the background and use absolute positioning to set the offset.

The CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.bg-skew {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/50/50');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
}
```

You can also use a pseudo element instead of an explicitly defined element.

The reason you might use this approach would be if you had a pre-defined parent container.

Answer (score 0):

use a div ( you probably want to use z-index:-1;) with:

```
position: fixed;
margin-left:50%;
width:50%;
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mt2JS/5/)